# vb.net cannot run in network by other user

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012-express

Currently I'm creating a new system using vb.2012 with a SQL Server 2012 Express database. The SQL Server database is installed on my computer, now I'm trying to run my system on another computer through network and connect to the SQL Server database, but an error shows up:

> Cannot connect database "ITSystem" request by login. The login failed, Login failed for user 'fpcsb\administrator'

Kindly help me with this. Thank you

PS: the `.exe` file copy from the debug folder and run in other computer. This issue not related to remote connection in SQL, i had follow the step to solve this issue but the error still remain

Comment: Does the login `fpcsb\administrator` exist in the SqlServer?

Comment: looks like you set up the user for the sql db as local administrator for the machine the database was on. Now that you have moved the db the account will not be the same. You should create a separate sql user for the db and not use a local admin account.

Comment: Actually... reading more into this... you don't mention you have moved the db only the app. I would suggest you check your connection string settings. You may have used local, localhost or . (dot) which whould make any exe look for the db on the machine it is running from.

Comment: @adrianm  "fpcsb\administrator" is a domain name for the server, i can run in my computer, but when i copy the .exe file to other computer then the error will appear

Comment: @Mych You are right, the DB install in my computer, so i can run the system, the problem is i just copy the .exe file from the debug folder and paste it at other computer and run it. Or i should make it as installer package and run it at another computer ? This is my connection code (Server=192.168.1.121\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ITSystem;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing= True ;User=admin; Password=admin;")

Comment: Ok. So this is an internal network. Are all other computers that you installed the front end exe on the same network?

Comment: Hi all, i solved this issue by add the ‘fpcsb\administrator’ user in SQL express and set the permission to allow access to DB. Thank for your help.